# How can I find out where the message is sent from

Tags: xcode, debugging, release, nszombie

I am using a obj-c port of an open-source library and there seems to be a bug in it. 
It is very large, and stepping through it is not really an option.

I have been able to figure out that the crash is caused by the following.

`-[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d847aa0`

Is there a way for me to find out where the message originates from or better yet what object hides behind: `0x1d847aa0`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "Enable Zombie Objects" in the "Diagnostics" tab of the "Edit Scheme ..." setting.

Xcode will then break if a message is sent to an deallocated instance.

You can also profile with Instruments, using the "Zombies" tool, this will display the entire alloc/retain/release history for the zombie object:

[image]

Comment: I enabled Zombie Objects in the Scheme. But when I use Instruments (Product > Profile) I can not select "Zombies" so I instead chose "Leaks". I then run through the program an when it crashes a small black box with an x is added to the time line and I just get a popup says `AppName Terminated`. In my console output I get the error message mentioned above (`CALayer release...`).

Comment: @Casper: Strange, when I profile, "Zombies" is in the "Memory" section of Instruments, together with "Allocations" and "Leaks". But (I think that) Zombies is just an option of the "Allocations" tool, so you could start Instruments with "Allocations", click on the small "i" icon and "Enable NSZombie detection". - The "Enable Zombie Objects" option in the Xcode scheme is used only when you run the project in Xcode, not for Instruments.

Comment: I found it. It appears when I run in the simulator. I normally test directly on a device.